# I'm getting a syntax error on my IF statement, not sure why?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, pdfminer

I'm trying to run the following code in python 3.7. I keep getting a invalid syntax error and not sure why, can someone spot what i'm doing wrong? Indent seems to be fine, my "Prints" are in correct brackets i believe but i'm totally lost on the "if" and "else" statements.

```
class pdfPositionHandling:

    def parse_obj(self, lt_objs):

        # loop over the object list
        for obj in lt_objs:

            if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextLine):
                print ("%6d, %6d, %s" % (obj.bbox[0], obj.bbox[1], obj.get_text().replace('\n', '_'))

            # if it's a textbox, also recurse
            if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                self.parse_obj(obj._objs)

            # if it's a container, recurse
            elif isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTFigure):
                self.parse_obj(obj._objs)

    def parsepdf(self, filename, startpage, endpage):

        # Open a PDF file.
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')

        # Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
        parser = PDFParser(fp)

        # Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
        # Password for initialization as 2nd parameter
        document = PDFDocument(parser)

        # Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
        if not document.is_extractable:
            raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

        # Create a PDF resource manager object that stores shared resources.
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

        # Create a PDF device object.
        device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)

        # BEGIN LAYOUT ANALYSIS
        # Set parameters for analysis.
        laparams = LAParams()

        # Create a PDF page aggregator object.
        device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

            # Create a PDF interpreter object.
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)


        i = 0
        # loop over all pages in the document
        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
            if i >= startpage and i <= endpage:
                # read the page into a layout object
                interpreter.process_page(page)
                layout = device.get_result()

                # extract text from this object
                self.parse_obj(layout._objs)
            i += 1
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/951298/Documents/Python Scripts/PDF Scraping/untitled1.py", line 12
    if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure why its point at the colon at the end?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in the print statement above your if statement.

Comment: Suggestion: use an IDE that will identify things like a missing parenthesis right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 9 you should have typed 3 parenthesses inthe end but you only had 2 of them.Add another parenthes and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place the ending bracket on your print statement. This causes an error on the next line because the interpreter ignores newlines when reading the code inside the brackets. In fact, the only reason it threw an error on line 12 is because `if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):` is is not a valid argument to pass to print.

Therefore, the following code would throw an error on line 11.

```
bar = "a"
baz = "a"

def foo(msg, bar="\n"):
    print(msg, end=bar)

if bar == baz:
    foo("bar is equal to baz",
    bar = baz

else: #Throws error here
    foo("bar is not equal to baz")

#Not the best example, I know, sorry.
```

Odd, is it not? Be sure to take a look the line(s) above the line that throws an error. It gives you both context, and a potential erroneous code. You especially need to watch for these kinds of errors in programming languages that require newline terminators.

Answer (score 0):

In line 9 you should have 3 ending parenthesis, but I also happened to notice that you have two if statements and one elif statement but no else, they should all be if statements. Hope I helped!